# Watch SCSS keeps creating an index.css

Tags: html, css, sass, settings

I'm new to SCSS and I'm using VS Code's extension to watch my SCSS, I've set-up my settings.json file and everything works - however - when I watch my SCSS files and save, it creates two .css files.

- index.css
- main.css

## Index.css is an empty .css file

## Main.css is a .css file with all of my styling in it.

Why does it keep on generating the empty index.css file ?

Here is my settings.json file's content to help out a little.

```
{
    "editor.accessibilitySupport": "off",
    "window.zoomLevel": 0,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Night Owl",
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    // "python.jediEnabled": false,
    "[python]": {

    },
    "editor.fontFamily": "Input",
    "editor.fontSize": 16,
    "[php]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "kokororin.vscode-phpfmt"
    },
    "liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": [],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "compact",
            "extensionName": ".css",
            "savePath": "/dist/assets/css"
        }
    ],
    "liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a partial without adding `_` in front of it.

Here is my folder structure with my file named **wrong**:

```
- scss
    - pages
        - pages.scss
```

Here is my folder structure with my file named **correctly**:

```
- scss
    - pages
        - _pages.scss
```